# php query array

Tags: php, sql

I have an array like this:

```
$array=[
    0 => [col_a => 1, col_b => 2, col_c =>3],
    1 => [col_a => 2, col_b => 3, col_c =>4]
];
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
$result=query_array($array,"SELECT col_c FROM ARRAY WHERE col_a=2 AND col_b=3");
print_r($result);
// array (col_c => 4)
```

EDIT:

where `query_array` is a function that executes SQL to an array.

I know I can loop between the elements and test every "row". I was wondering if there is a build-in function that does that like that fictional `query_array` function.

Comment: nope, it's not *query_array*, you could only filter it based on its keys or value. [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) if you're interested..

Comment: well, if you really need it, you could use [`array_filter(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and make the callbacks to emulate your *where* clause..

Answer (score 1):

```
 $array=[
    0 => ['col_a' => 1, 'col_b' => 2, 'col_c' =>3],
    1 => ['col_a' => 2, 'col_b' => 3, 'col_c' =>4]
];


$val1 =2;
$val2 = 3;
$isArray = array_values(array_filter($array, function ($data) use ($val1,$val2) {
    return ($data['col_a'] == $val1 &&  $data['col_b'] == $val2);
}));
```

Comment: additional note, this will not preserve original array's key.. while `array_filter` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrays = [
   ['col_a' => 1, 'col_b' => 2, 'col_c' => 3],
   ['col_a' => 2, 'col_b' => 3, 'col_c' => 4]
];


foreach ($arrays as $array) {
   $res = array_filter($array, function($v, $k) {
      return ($k == 'col_a' && $v == 2) || ($k == 'col_b' && $v == 3);
   }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

   if (count($res) == 2) {
      print_r([
          'col_c' => $array['col_c']
      ]);
   }
}
```

Try something like this